# In Apex test class- can we call same method with different senario

Tags: apex

I have a apex class, that has a method  **handleWebServiceResponse(res.getBody().trim());**  ,In my test class i have to test this method by different senario.

For example:
res.getBody().trim() --> Expected valid Json

```
@isTest
static void testhandleWebServiceResponse(){

    PageReference pageRef = Page.CreateSalesOrder;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id',''); //Without Passing Id value
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    CreateOrder con = new CreateOrder(); 
    // Passing valid Json response in handleWebServiceResponse() with empty value in Id of the page parameters
    con.handleWebServiceResponse('{"auth_token": "e963a669e30a815983b9dab6fe688b516299b2d0e2927e1119b0f4874394f3ce8e963216799d443ac55fdd9ddf240db7d732ca350e0e5d9b3ff29a207086b2132f37ecd52e1043d02a62b0be4d2afd68d2457ba8b3f4aa4a7a197b9b28229f12b5f6efd0", "expires_on": "2018-09-21T10:37:04.271Z"}');

    // Passing null value in handleWebServiceResponse()
    con.handleWebServiceResponse(null);     

    // Passing Invalid Json response in handleWebServiceResponse()
    con.handleWebServiceResponse('{{"message": "User not found"}');

    PageReference pageref1 = con.getRedir(); 
}
```

in my test class,In single method **testhandleWebServiceResponse** am testing the method with different scenario, Is this the right way or we need to write separate method for each scenario, Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly test more than one scenario in a single method, but I usually write a separate method for each scenario.  That way, if I know just one scenario is failing, I can run that test on its own as I work through the problem.  Keeps things moving a little faster that way.

I see that you don't have any assertions in your test method.  That's no good! Taking a look over the resources below will help you write more effective unit tests...which will make your work a lot simpler in the long run!

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests